# How to fine tune BERT on unlabeled data?

Tags: nlp, pytorch, huggingface-transformers, bert-language-model

I want to fine tune BERT on a specific domain. I have texts of that domain in text files. How can I use these to fine tune BERT?
I am looking [here](https://huggingface.co/transformers/model_doc/bert.html#bertforpretraining) currently.

My main objective is to get sentence embeddings using BERT.

Answer (score 14):

The important distinction to make here is whether you want to **fine-tune** your model, or whether you want to expose it to additional **pretraining**.

The former is simply a way to train BERT to adapt to a specific *supervised task*, for which you generally need in the order of 1000 or more samples **including labels**.

Pretraining, on the other hand, is basically trying to help BERT better "understand" data from a certain domain, by basically continuing its unsupervised training objective (`[MASK]`ing specific words and trying to predict what word should be there), for which you do *not* need labeled data.

If your ultimate objective is sentence embeddings, however, I would strongly suggest you to have a look at [Sentence Transformers](https://github.com/UKPLab/sentence-transformers), which is based on a slightly outdated version of Huggingface's transformers library, but primarily tries to generate high-quality embeddings. Note that there are ways to train with surrogate losses, where you try to emulate some form ofloss that is relevant for embeddings.

**Edit:** The author of Sentence-Transformers recently joined Huggingface, so I expect support to greatly improve over the upcoming months!

Comment: I want to do additional pretraining. Looking at the link to "Sentence Transformers," it looks like what I want is in the section "Continue Training on Other Data." Can I use unlabeled texts as training data here? The link to the py file mentioned in that section doesn't exist anymore.

Comment: @Rish did you find a solution? I'm looking for the same. I want to do additional pretraining for a particular domain.

Comment: @Miguel I ended up trying this: [DeCLUTR](https://github.com/JohnGiorgi/DeCLUTR)

Comment: @Rish - how did it perform?

Answer (score 2):

@dennlinger gave an exhaustive answer. Additional pretraining is also referred as "post-training", "domain adaptation" and "language modeling fine-tuning". [here](https://github.com/huggingface/transformers/tree/master/examples/pytorch/language-modeling) you will find an example how to do it.

But, since you want to have good sentence embeddings, you better use [Sentence Transformers](https://github.com/UKPLab/sentence-transformers). Moreover, they provide fine-tuned models, which already capable of understanding semantic similarity between sentences. "Continue Training on Other Data" section is what you want to further fine-tune the model on your domain. You do have to prepare training dataset, according to one of available [loss functions](https://www.sbert.net/docs/package_reference/losses.html). E.g. `ContrastLoss` requires a pair of texts and a label, whether this pair is similar.

Comment: Hi @pashok3ddd, I'm trying to post-train a transformers model on my own domain-specific text. Unfortunately, the link to the example you posted does not exist. Do you have any other recommendations on where I can get a code for this task?

Answer (score 0):

I believe transfer learning is useful to train the model on a specific domain. First you load the pretrained base model and freeze its weights, then you add another layer on top of the base model and train that layer based on your own training data. However, the data would need to be labelled.

Tensorflow has some useful [guide](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/keras/transfer_learning) on transfer learning.

Answer (score 0):

You are talking about `pre-training`. Fine-tuning on unlabeled data is called pre-training and for getting started, you can take a look over [here](https://github.com/google-research/bert#pre-training-with-bert).